# Change tooltip on other element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Is it possible to change the tooltip of other element when button is clicked?
I want the tooltip to be always visible, but when click on button the tooltip of element must change his value

Example :

Tooltip: Button is not clicked; -> Button is clicked!

Here is my code...

```js
$(function() {
  $('.resetPrice').tooltip();
  $('#thumbs').click(
    function(e) {
      $('.resetPrice').tooltip('toggle');
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div>
  <button id="thumbs" type="button" class="btn btn-mini">
        <i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>
    </button>

  <button title="Clicked" type="button" class="btn btn-mini resetPrice" data-placement='bottom'>
        <i class="icon-refresh"> </i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.resetPrice').attr('title', 'Toggle').tooltip('fixTitle')` or `$('.resetPrice').attr('title', 'Toggle').tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');`